# C - scanf value directly from terminal

Tags: c, linux, terminal, output

I have a c process that waits for a `scanf()` input.

I want to save its results to a `*.txt` file.
To terminal (linux)

```
./process > out.txt
```

What's the way to write in terminal the scanf prehand?

Thanks.

Comment: Look at here : http://askubuntu.com/questions/420981/how-do-i-save-terminal-output-to-a-file

Comment: @KcDoD IMHO, that part is already known to OP. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the below program you could give the input as.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main ()                                      
{
    int i = 0;                                       
    scanf("%d", &i);
    printf("Value of i = %d\n", i);
    return 0;
}
```

---

```
$ gcc -o exe file.c
$ echo 2 | ./exe
Value of i = 2
```

`|` or `pipeline` connects two commands together *so that the output from one program becomes the input of the next program*.

Update:
If you want to read string, or strings and ints together

```
int i = 0;
char str[20];                            
scanf("%d%s", &i, str);                         
printf("Value of i = %d\nValue of str = %s\n", i, str);
```

---

```
$ echo "45 John" | ./exe   # Ensure your input sequence is correct #
Value of i = 45
Value of str = John
```

---

For saving the output to file `output.txt`

```
$ echo "45 John" | ./exe  > output.txt
$ cat output.txt 
Value of i = 45
Value of str = John
```

Comment: Thanks! That worked! Give some points to mark this as solution!

Answer (score 2):

You can give the input like following.

One is piping,

```
 cat filename | ./process > sample.txt
```

Or else you can give like this

```
 ./process < filename > sample.txt
```

Or else

```
 echo "1" | ./process > sample.txt
```

In that file, you can only place the integer value and gave like this.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The process requests for a value input. Specifically it is an integer.

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing this is to write your scanf() input into a text file. Your input text file should be properly formatted according to scanf() sequence. Then redirect your input text file to program binary and redirect shell output of program binary to output file.

Use following command to execute your binary.

```
./main < input.txt  > output.txt
```

For example:

If your main.c looks as follows

```
scanf("%s\n", &my_string);
scanf("%d\n", &my_int);
```

Then you should prepare an input.txt as follows

```
Hello
31
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main ()                                      
{
    int i = 0;                                       
    printf("Enter value of i:");
    scanf("%d", &i);
    printf("Value of i = %d\n", i);
    return 0;
}
```

if I want to give dynamic input value of i. how to give it?

in the following code static value is given by echo.

```
$ gcc -o exe file.c
$ echo 2 | ./exe
Value of i = 2
```

it should display printf statement in file and from that file I should be able to give input instead of terminal.